# Derived node.js EventEmitter will call the wrong listener when in a named object property

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

I've been working on creating my own home automation hub using a handful of node.js packages (Express, mqtt, socket.io) with a MongoDB database and Angular running in the client. This project is the first time I've worked with any JavaScript, so it's safe to say I'm a bit of a noob.

I've been troubleshooting an issue with derived EventEmitters calling the wrong listener function when referenced as a named property. Here's a minimal example that will demonstrate the problem:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var debug = require('debug')('test.js');
var util = require('util');

var TestEmitter = function (initialState, name) {
    var self = this;
    EventEmitter.call(self);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.name = name;
    this.setState = function (newState) {
        self.emit('change', newState, this.state);
        self.state = newState;
    };
};
util.inherits(TestEmitter, EventEmitter);

var myObj = {
    ary: [new TestEmitter(false, 'ary1'), new TestEmitter(true, 'ary2')],
    named: {
        name1: new TestEmitter(3, 'name1'),
        name2: new TestEmitter(4, 'name2')
    }
};

myObj.ary.forEach(function (aryEmitter) {
    aryEmitter.on('change', function (newState) {
        debug(aryEmitter.name + ' changed to: ' + newState);
    });
});
for (var prop in myObj.named) {
    var currEmitter = myObj.named[prop];
    debug('prop = ' + prop);
    debug('name = ' + currEmitter.name);
    currEmitter.on('change', function (newState) {
        debug(currEmitter.name + ' changed to: ' + newState);
    });
}

myObj.ary[0].setState(true);
myObj.ary[1].setState(false);
myObj.named.name1.setState(4);
myObj.named.name2.setState(5);
```

Essentially, `TestEmitter` is an object derived from `EventEmitter` that will broadcast a `change` event when its `setState` method is called.

`myObj` is a reference to four `TestEmitter` instances -- two in an array, and two in named properties. After creating `myObj`, I register a listener for each of their `change` events that simply writes debugging output to the console with the name of the `TestEmitter` instance whose callback is being invoked.

However, the named `TestEmitter` references don't work the way that I would expect. The call to both `myObj.named.name1.setState(4)` as well as `myObj.named.name2.setState(5)` will both execute the callback function that I registered for the `EventEmitter` `myObj.named.name2`. Running everything above will produce the following output:

```
test.js prop = name1 +0ms
test.js name = name1 +5ms
test.js prop = name2 +0ms
test.js name = name2 +0ms
test.js ary1 changed to: true +0ms
test.js ary2 changed to: false +0ms
test.js name2 changed to: 4 +0ms
test.js name2 changed to: 5 +0ms
```

Can anyone offer any help? I've read a fair amount about the best way to create derived `EventEmitters` and it looks like I'm taking the right approach, so I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks for reading and any help you're able to offer!

Comment: You're looking for `bind` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind or use arrow functions in `forEach` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem becomes at this part of the code:

```
for (var prop in myObj.named) {
    var currEmitter = myObj.named[prop];
    debug('prop = ' + prop);
    debug('name = ' + currEmitter.name);
    currEmitter.on('change', function (newState) {
        debug(currEmitter.name + ' changed to: ' + newState);
    });
}
```

So that when an event is fired, inside the function handler, `currEmitter` has the value of the last element of `loop`.

One simple fix is to use encapsule it in a function, to create a new scope, and do the things inside this function :

```
for (var prop in myObj.named) {
    var currEmitter = myObj.named[prop];
    (function(currEmitter){
      currEmitter.on('change', newState=>{
        debug(currEmitter.name + ' changed to: ' + newState);
      });
    })(currEmitter);
}
```

Or you can use `Object.keys()`:

```
Object.keys(myObj.named).forEach(function(key){
  var currEmitter = myObj.named[key];
  currEmitter.on('change', function(newState){
    debug(currEmitter.name + ' changed to: ' + newState);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input -- I'll definitely need to do a bit of reading about these arrow functions. 

But, even without knowing more about them, I'd like to point out -- the anonymous functions within the `myObj.ary.forEach` loop work as expected. It's the `for(var prop in myObj.named)` loop that's misbehaving.

Comment: You edited your answer so now I look like a crazy person :)

Would you mind helping me understand the difference between `Object.keys(myObj.named).forEach(function(key){})` and `for (var key in myObj.named){}`? Why do these produce different results?

Comment: `Object.keys()` takes a function, which it means that creates a `new scope`, that scope is accesible for the handler. In the case of `for(var prop in obj)` no scope is created.

Comment: @JoshGordon Sorry one more time. See edit. Forget about Arrow functions, It was my mistake. Here you have a fiddle that reproduce different behaviours: https://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/uazyb64r/